# How to check for conflicts on recurring events using Google Calendar API?

Tags: javascript, python, google-calendar-api

I want to check if a recurring event would conflict with any event in the calendar using Google Calendar API.

Can some direct some example of this?   I've seen the free/busy documentation but this does not account for specific recurring event conflicts. For example I wouldn't be able to do the below:

For example how would I if there are any conflicts if I create an event happening only on Mondays, Tuesdays and Wednesay at 3pm to 5pm from today and end the end of the month.

Comment: Have you checked this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44133947/google-calendar-api-check-for-conflicts) answered by DaImTo? She used the method [freebusy](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query) and basically returns a list of events between a two times if they exist within a calendar.

Comment: I have looked at how to use free busy but how does freebusy enable me to check for conflicts for recurring events?  For example I want to book every monday from march 1st to march 20th, 3pm to 5pm.   So do I iterate through every week to check if the mondays are available?